# Looking for the sum of factors equal to the number of oneself

Tags: c

I'm trying to finish my homework, while there is something trapped me.

Here the question:
In the range of N, output those numbers whose factors sum is equal to themselves according to the following format.

Input:

```
1000
```

output:

```
6 its factors are 1 2 3 
28 its factors are 1 2 4 7 14 
496 its factors are 1 2 4 8 16 31 62 124 248
```

Here my code, please tell me why can't i get the right output. Appreciate it if 
you can improve it for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM 100
int main()
    {
    int goal[NUM];//array for factors.
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    getchar();
    for(int p=2;p<N;p++)//1 and N are not included.
     {
        int j=0,sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<p; )
        {
            //get factors and put them into array.
            while(p%i==0)
            {
                goal[j]=i;
                sum+=goal[j];
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        //judge the sum of factors and p the two values are equal.
        if(sum==p)
        {
            printf("%d its factors are ",p);

            for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                while(i==j-1)
                printf("%d \n",goal[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The `while(p%i==0)` doesn't seem to be doing what you propose it to do. How about dividing this code to functions and testing theme one by one?

Comment: At first glance what i guess is its because you need to do `sum=0` inside for loop.

Comment: It's a good idea to use a function, but I still can't figure out the problem in the while loop.

Comment: @Mihir But I 've declared and defined it as a global variable.

Comment: @clockstream, sum is `not` a global variable. Also even if it was, your sums are independent for every number, so every time it needs to be started from 0.

Comment: @Mihir I got it, sum shouldn't be global variable, to a new p it needs to be started from 0.

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: I'll go to see if i can get the right answer.

Comment: @Mihir still can't get the right answer. It even didn't give the output.

Comment: @clockstream, I have retained your coding style and edited your code and posted an answer. I have added commenst whereever you made mistakes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the same a little clean,

```
int main()
{
    int N, factors_sum, factors_cnt, num, j;

    scanf("%d", &N);

    int *factors = malloc(sizeof(int) * N/2);

    if (factors == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc(2)");
        return 1;
    }

    for (num = 2 ; num < N ; ++num)
    {
        factors_cnt = 0;
        factors_sum = 0;
        for (j = 1 ; j <= num/2 ; ++j)
            if (num % j == 0)
                factors_sum += (factors[factors_cnt++] = j);

        if (factors_sum == num)
        {
            printf("%d its factors are", num);
            for (j = 0 ; j < factors_cnt ; ++j)
                printf(" %d", factors[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(factors);
    return 0;
}
```

Modifications retaining your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM 100
int main()
    {
    int goal[NUM];//array for factors.
    int sum=0;
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    //getchar(); // I donno why you need this, better to remove it
    for(int p=2;p<N;p++)//1 and N are not included.
    {
        // sum is different for every number
        // need to be set to 0 individually for every number
        sum = 0; 
        int j=0;
        for(int i=1;i<p; i++) // i++ everytime
        {
            //get factors and put them into array.
            if (p%i==0)
            // changed while to if
            // while would keep executing forever
            {
                goal[j]=i;
                sum+=goal[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        //judge the sum of factors and p the two values are equal.
        if (sum==p)
        {
            printf("%d its factors are ",p);

            for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                // no need for while here
                printf("%d \n",goal[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I have made modifications in your code and corrected/commented where you have made mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's right though there is something wrong with the output format. BTW, the function getchar() is my copy from others, but i've forgot its function. somebody thinks it is necessary behind scanf

Comment: @clockstream, most probably you mean your factors are displayed on newlines? To display them on single line, you need to change `printf("%d \n",goal[i]);` to `printf("%d ",goal[i]);`

Comment: Most prolly you may have encountered those issues where there is a `\n` in the buffer which doesn't let you take the input. Although, getchar() is just a workaround in that case. Also, it not the case here.